# What are some good dictionaries about Mathematics?

Tags: dictionary

I have found a dictionary about Mathematics; however, it goes from Chinese to English.  I have tried different bookstores in my city, but they don't have an English to Chinese dictionary.

I have looked on 淘宝, but I'd like to find something of good/great quality, as I don't really trust the reviews that I have seen on there.

Comment: Maoyiyi, and everyone, I reopened this because someone else asked for the same thing. And I think it'd be ok to add this to the [Chinese Resources question](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1120/43).

Comment: I'm also interested in resources for jargon in various subjects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is 汉英数学词典 and what you are looking for is 英汉数学词典. If you google 英汉数学词典, you can find a few sources for downloading. You can also search book-selling websites, and you will get a few choices.

Comment: do you know of any good math (college level) websites in Chinese?

Comment: I am not majored in math, but you can google 大学数学 to find college level math websites in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent way to translate technical vocabulary:

1. Find the term in English on Wikipedia.
2. Go to the "Languages" list in the left sidebar and find 中文

Not all articles have a Chinese translation (and sometimes they do, but they're not properly linked together), but when they do, it's a very reliable way to translate technical terms.